# Content Provider for abstracting API requests and caching?

Tags: android

I'm learning android app dev and need to separate the UI and the part which makes network API calls, there may be caching in future.

Should I use a *Content Provider* class for wrapping up the data fetching and caching ?
How would I benefit from it ?

Or, should I just make a custom class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you could check this [Google I/O video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) about REST best practices - it's real nice)))

`ContentProvider` would give you a possibility to use `ContentObserver` to monitor changes in `ContentProvider` and automatically refetch data to UI. But you would need to implement lot's of different things and write lots of code.

Second approach is to use `SQLiteOpenHelper` + manually notify you UI about changes in DB (your cache) via `LocalBroadcast`, for example.

I think both ways are useable, so it's up to you and depends only on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Another thought is to use Google's Loader Class since it persists through rotation and you can implement a loader to run basic Http Connectivity as seen [here.](https://github.com/ChristopherTulip/MapHomeTest/blob/master/src/com/tulip/maphometest/API/BasicLoader.java) Bear in mind everything Evos said was true this is just another idea / alternative.

Also look into [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

I used two libraries and combined it into one custom class.

The [`AsyncHttpClient`](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) is used to make the network calls and [`DataManagement`](http://epsilonlabsllc.github.com/DataManagement/) (a simple database) for the caching.

The custom class will check if the cache is available in the database. If it is available, it will return the data from the cache. If it is not, the network call is made and the response will be cached in the database.